# Updating Cross references in Microsoft word

Tags: ms-word, cross-reference

Does anybody know how to update cross references in word. I am writing a report and have to provide references for the same. If I change the reference number how can I update it in entire document. For eg. If I have given reference number as [10] and if its updated to [11] how can I change it in entire document? Tried with select all text and updating fields, but its not solving the purpose....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the entire document by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all selected cross-reference fields.

Answer (score 0):

While pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>F9</kbd> may suffice for basic documents, this approach does not update the figure numbers inside text boxes. One common instance where this issue arises is when you add a caption to an image with a layout style other than "In Line with Text." In such cases, MS Word inserts the caption inside a text box.

### A More Effective Solution:

To reliably update numbering for figures, tables, and even cross-references, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the print preview. This action forces MS Word to update all numbers. To exit the print preview and return to your document, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.